# Battery duration instead of battery percentage

Tags: battery, notification-bar, notification-icons

I wonder if there is a way to modify my battery icon in order to present battery remaining in hours/minutes/etc and not in a percentage form

Comment: Just a note: remaining duration might not be a good indicator for general purpose since it depends on current activity. Though you may have a reason why you want it.

Comment: @AndrewT. in android version Jellybean is the battery percentage really correct or its just approximate considering all the apps are force closed except the android core modules.

Comment: @user285oo6 it should be correct because it reads from the voltage level. Apps force closing is not related to battery, but memory.